# Can I paginate a query in Sql Server without using ROW_NUM () OVER (ORDER BY xxxxx)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2005, data-access-layer

I'm working on a custom DAL and am now dealing with automatic result pagination. The DAL generates dynamic queries based on our models, like:

```
Model.All() --> generates "select * from mytable"
Model.Filter ("d=@0", "arg0value") --> generates "select * from mytable where d=@0"
...
```

I don't want to add extra parameters to our filter functions, nor specialized functions for paginating (well, if it's avoidable, of course). Instead, I'd like to paginate the results changing the query *before* it gets executed. Something like...

```
var resultset = Model.Filter ("d=@0, "arg0value"); // "select * from mytable where d=@0"
resulset = resultset.Paginate (1, 25); // this should paginate the query before loading any objects
```

In Oracle it's easy, using the ROWNUM pseudocolumn and wrapping the old query.

```
select * from (my old sql) where rownum between 20 and 40
```

In Sql Server (2005) there's nothing like ROWNUM. I've seen there is the ROW_NUMBER function, but it requires knowing the inners of the query, as you need to pass an "OVER (ORDER BY xxxx)" clause.

```
select row_number() over (order By <?????>) as rownum, dv.* from (my old sql) as dv where rownum between 20 and 40
```

So, is there a way to perform this in Sql Server without adding specific parameters/functions to our models?

Thanks!

**Edit**

As @Dems says, I could parse the query and add the ORDER BY based on the output fields, but: first, I don't want the overhead of parsing, and second, if the query is of type "select *", I can't extract the fields.

Comment: In SQL Server 2012, there will be [OFFSET and FETCH NEXT](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx) - but until then, the CTE with `ROW_NUMBER()` is your only really viable choice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're writing your own data access layer, and you want to apply ROW_NUMBER() only knowing the query's output field names (rather than it's internals)...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY field1, field2, field3) AS row_id,
    *
  FROM
  (
    <your-query>
  )
    AS unordered_data
)
  AS ordered_data
WHERE
  row_id BETWEEN x AND y
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if the prev query is "select * ..." I can't extract the fields. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Then your only available option is to control the records pulled in your client, possibly using the record set.  This can be used to avoid network traffic of pulling over unnecessary records, but won't save any load on your SQL Server.

Comment: It seems I'll have to add some specific functions, so I can use the model metadata during the query generation. I'll wait a time. If there isn't a better answer, I'll accept this, for insightful. Thanks.